# How to solve Visual C++ window form disappearance?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, managed-c++

I have a visual c++ program which has a few window forms. It does not have any error and can be built successfully. Today I want to add another textbox and a button to one of the form, but I cannot find out my form design window. I see the Form1.h,  Form1.resX and my other stuff. Once again, I can built it and the program does not have any error, but the form design window disappear. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

For VS2008

1. Click View->Resource View or in the Solution Explorer click the Resource View tab
2. Under "App.rc" click Dialog, you can view your form there

Comment: I see the "App.rc" click Dialog, but I only see an "Icon" folder there. The "Icon" folder only contain an app.ico